# Open .aspx page with report controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, reportviewer2008

I have an MVC .cshtml page with a button. It's in a grid and I am passing the row ids to the controller using the jquery

```
<button type="submit" id="btn_View" name="view"
      class="btn_View">

 $(".btn_View_Question").click(function () { 

            var json = [];
            var obj = {};

            var rowID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            obj.RowId= rowID ;


            console.log(obj);
            json.push(obj)
            var responseDetails = JSON.stringify(json);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/View",
                type: "POST",
                data: responseDetails,
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            });

        });
```

In the controller class I am redirecting to a aspx report page as follows

```
public RedirectResult ViewQuestionnaire(string[] id)
    {
  var reportParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 reportParameters.Add("ID", id[0]);
 Session["reportParameters"] = reportParameters;
return Redirect("../Reports/ViewQuestionarie.aspx");
}
```

The aspx page is not loading. When I debug it the page_load of the aspx page also executing. What might the wrong thing I am doing here

Comment: your action method is expecting a string value and your ajax code is sending an array. Are you sure this is correct ?

Comment: Sorry. I missed the array part I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect is going to return a 302 response with the new url as the location header value.You should not be making the call to an action method which returns a 302 response from an ajax call.

Looks like you want to set some data to Session. You may use your ajax call to still do that part. Instead of returning a 302 response,return a json data structure with the url you want the browser to be redirected.

```
public ActionResult ViewQuestionnaire(string[] id)
{
    var reportParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    reportParameters.Add("ID", id[0]);
    Session["reportParameters"] = reportParameters;
    return Json(new {status = "success", url="../Reports/ViewQuestionarie.aspx"});      
}
```

And in the `success` / `done` event of the ajax call, you can read the url property of the json response coming back and use that to do the redirection.

```
$.ajax({

    //Omitted some parameters 

    success: function(res) {
        if (res.status === "success") {
            window.location.href = res.url;
        }
    }
});
```